# Customize or Create Picture Style in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-word, email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, office365

I often use the same picture style when pasting (not attaching) images into e-mails in Outlook. Even with the Ribbon, setting this style every time is a 4-click process.

Is there anyway to set a picture style (Picture Tools | Format >> Picture Styles) as default on every paste, preferably without creating a macro?

I saw this question posted once in another place from ages ago, but this is an active item for me. Modifying the picture style makes it look much nicer in emails so I use it constantly, but there isn't a default selection that I like so I'd like to customize.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anyway to set a picture style (Picture Tools | Format >> Picture Styles) as default on every paste, preferably without creating a macro?

Still not feasible without using macro. There's no native feature available in Outlook to set a custom picture style as default.

Came across the similar feature request in the official feedback portal for Outlook and I've voted it up. You can also add vote or comment there so that possibly the engineering team could prioritize it.

https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/97edfb25-5306-ee11-a81c-000d3ae5b6f4

Meanwhile, when you need to paste multiple pictures into a same message, you can utilize the "Format Painter" to avoid the tedious 4-click process:

1. When all the pictures have been added into the message body, format the 1st image according to your preferences and needs.
2. Select the image, DOUBLE CLICK the "Format Painter" on the ribbon.
   [image: List item]
3. Click on the other pictures one by one to paint" the format onto them.
   [image]

Comment: Good info - yes I use format painter a lot. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to know that it helped : )

Answer (score 0):

After landing on this post while looking for an answer to the same problem, I just found a workaround that I'm happy with, which may work for you.  It won't work on paste, but should reduce your steps if you keep the style menu handy (I put it in the Quick Access Bar).

1. Create a new style based on paragraph
2. Format > Border:

   - Choose style/color/width to taste (do this first)
   - Then choose "Box" on the left
   - Still in the border formatting dialog, click on "Options..." I recommend values greater than 1 to make sure all borders remain visible.  You can play with this.
3. Format > Frame:

   - Text wrapping: None

Boom!

Once you've pasted your image, you can apply this style to it.  Works on Windows at least - don't know about other OS's.

HTH